# How to use app-shell with prerender in Angular SSR

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal

I am building an app this is SSO friendly. It has few static pages and few uses dynamic SSR. I'm currently using prerendering for static pages. But app-shell gives excellent first paint metrics.

Here I want to use both app-shell and prerendering, how to do this in Angular?

Comment: what is an app-shell?

Comment: Please refer: https://angular.io/guide/app-shell

Comment: hmmm. looks like ssr, but with data loading. Why not use only ng-universal? He can render page without reload data, but u must use BrowserTransferStateModule (in browser module) & ServerTransferStateModule (for server module). In components just use private transferState: TransferState and transferState.set(key, <any>value) & transferState.get(key, <any>default_value). But if u use map into classes u must remap data in front side

Comment: We are using angular universal for SSR. But we want to encash the advantage of both app-shell and prerendering. With the default configuration, we can only do either app-shell or prerender prod builds.

Comment: without looking deeply into the topic why don t you do 2 builds 1 ssr 1 app-shell and let the backend decide which on to serve, provide ssr to search engine bots and appshell to users

Comment: This is also my question..